# Unable to import MySQLdb in ansible module

Tags: python, mysql-python, ansible

I am trying to write custom module in ansible. while using `import MySQLdb` it is giving me error

```
 failed: [127.0.0.1] => {"failed": true, "parsed": false}
invalid output was: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-1394199347.29-33439012674717/inventory", line 11, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

Using
**Python Version :** 2.6.6
**MySQL-python Version :** 1.2.3

Python Code:-

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import datetime
import sys
import json
import os
import shlex
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","user","pwd","db_name" )
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM hosts")
data = cursor.fetchone()
print data
db.close()
```

I have written a playbook to run ansible module:-

inventory.yaml:-

```
---
- hosts: webservers
  user: root
  sudo: True
  vars:
     act: list
  tasks:
  - name: Run module inventory
    action: inventory act="{{act}}" prod="roop"
```

I'm running this playbook using below commands:-

```
ansible-playbook -v playboook/path/inventory.yaml
```

Same code working in python command line (<<<) but not working in ansible module.

In my ansible module other code are working. 
Is there any configuration setting need to do for ansible??

Comment: Are you sure that the user you using to run the script has enough privileges to run MySQLdb module?

Comment: I running this script as a root user

Comment: Can you run with ANSIBLE_KEEP_REMOTE_FILES=1 and show the /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-xxx/inventory code ? Are you using virtualenv ?

Comment: @leucos. I have tried with ANSIBLE_KEEP_REMOTE_FILES same error message are displaying. and inventory code block same which I have mentioned in python code. No I am not using virtualenv

Comment: I meant use ANSIBLE_KEEP_REMOTE_FILES and chech the generated file (see ansible doc regarding module development)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your MySQLdb module is not in the Python environment. In your script you are running python using: `#!/usr/bin/python`. It's quite possible that the Python that you are running from the command line (`>>>`) is not the same Python.  You can try running:

```
which python
```

to find out which Python you are running off of.  So, if it's another Python to install it, you can run on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

or on CentOS, RedHat:

```
sudo yum install MySQL-python
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have already installed MySQL-python. Yes I will check if I am using different python.

Comment: Both using same python /usr/bin/python

Comment: How did you install Ansible?  using pip ? can you go to the Python command line and type `>>> import ansible` ? Do you get any error ?

Comment: I have extract ansible tar and setup env variable using `ansible/hacking/env-setup`. and `>>> import ansible` doesn't returning anything

Comment: Can you post your Ansible code that you are using to run this module ?

Comment: Well, without looking at it all I can say is that is an environment configuration.  The `python` that is running Ansible does't have `MySQLdb` module in it. The `MySQLdb` that you installed belongs to a `python` installation that is not running Ansible in your machine.  Or it could be that simply your `PYTHONPATH` variable is pointing to the wrong location.

Comment: two thing I was doing wrong here.
1) I need to run this script in local server, I was run for remote server
and 2) with my user permission related issue was there. 
I created new user and re configure again. then its working fine.
I am accepting your answer because you pointing me out towards my problem.
So partially it was helpful :) Thanks